# Why does knowing that the MLE of the mean = the arithmetic mean of the sample uniquely determine the Normal sampling distribution?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, maximum-likelihood, gaussian

Currently reading through E.T Jayne on Bayesian inference and in one chapter dedicated to the Normal distribution he argues that Gauss proved the following:

Given a sample from a population distribution with unknown mean, our MLE for the mean is the arithmetic mean of our sample *if and only if* the sampling distribution of the mean is Normal

I’m really struggling to see the intuition behind this, can anyone help out? Thanks!

Comment: I'm struggling to see how this statement is true: if the population distribution is just a Bernoulli trial with probability $p$, the maximum likelihood estimator of the mean is the sample arithmetic mean, but the sampling distribution of the mean is a scaled binomial distribution. Granted, it tends to a normal as the sample grows large, but that happens for basically every decently behaved random variable...

Comment: Also the ML estimate of the $\lambda$ parameter of the exponential distribution is the inverse of sample mean. Here $E(X)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ so I would say the ML estimate of the mean is the sample mean.

Answer (score 1):

You're referring to an argument Jaynes attributes to Gauss in Sec. 7.3. The log-likelihood of $n+1$ observations $\{x_i|0\le i\le n\}$ when the estimator is unbiased is of the form $\sum_i\ln f(x_i|\theta)$, which we want to maximise when $\theta=\bar{x}$.

Jaynes actually adds an assumption, which as @paulinho notes is inapplicable for the Bernoulli distribution, namely that the likelihood depends only on the $\theta-x_i$. If this seems like sleight of hand, bear in mind the point of his Chapter 7 is only to motivate why *sampling errors* would be Gaussian. (In particular, [*sampling means* being approximately Gaussian for large samples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) is a completely unrelated issue!) It is *not* an "everything is Gaussian" argument. (In fact, Sec. 7.12 explores why sometimes even errors would be non-Gaussian.) The assumption we're adding is reasonable for sampling errors.

Compare $\sum_i(\bar{x}-x_i)=0$ to $\left.\sum_i\frac1f\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\right|_{\theta=\bar{x}}=0$. For $\frac1f\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ to be proportional to $\theta-x$ (which is equivalent to $\ln f$ being quadratic in $\theta-x$ and peaked at $x=\theta$, making $\theta$ the mode of a Gaussian distribution) is clearly sufficient, and the case $x_i=-\tfrac1nx_n$ for all $i<n$, when $n\ge1$, proves necessity.

As for an intuition rather than a proof, note that if $\frac1f\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ is nonlinear you should be able to tweak initially constant $x_i$, without changing $\bar{x}$, so that $\frac1f\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ changes in value. The above example shows you can; see Jaynes for the full proof.

Comment: Thanks! But sorry can you elaborate on how this is an entirely unrelated issue to the normality of sampling means? Surely if the estimator is unbiased and the sampling error is normally distributed this implies a normal sample distribution around the true mean?

Comment: @Ablation_nation The sampling error is around a true sample value, not a true population mean. For example, whether the error in a measurement of my height is Normal is separate from whether heights are Normal.

Comment: Sorry maybe I’m getting mixed up on terminology here, by sampling error you mean the noise in the measurements E,g the epsilon in the linear regression model? If so I understand why that’s unrelated to the CLT, I thought you were referring to the sampling distribution

Comment: @Ablation_nation You've got it now. I'm talking about the meaurement error for a single sample. It should also be noted Jaynes is looking at the error's probability distribution from a Bayesian, not frequentist, perspective. Chapter 7 opens, "Here, de Morgan was expressing his bewilderment at the ‘curiously ubiquitous’ success of
methods of inference based on the Gaussian, or normal, ‘error law’ (sampling distribution), even in cases where the law is not at all plausible as a statement of the actual frequencies of the errors."